# Advanced IP Scanner Dead IP address

Tags: ip, lan, connection-sharing, internet-sharing

Currently, my laptop is connected to an AP. And then I share the Internet using Internet Sharing Connection to a device which is connected to my laptop by Ethernet cable.

However, when scanning this device with Advanced IP Scanner, I found both gateway (which is my Ethernet card) and the shared device are both dead. I cannot ssh to my device too.

Moreover, I also find out that my connected raspberry is assigned 2 different IP addresses.

[image: Advanced IP Scanner]

Could anyone can help me to fix my current problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I presume by 'dead' you mean you can't ping/connect to them?

Comment: Yes, I event cannot ping both my default gateway (192.168.137.1) or the Raspberry (192.168.137.76 or 192.168.137.86). All of them are request time out. However, when I plug my Raspberry into another laptop using Internet Connection Sharing, this other machine can ssh or ping to my raspberry. So problem I think must be inside my laptop...

Comment: Does the raspi get online from the original laptops ICS?

Comment: Yes. yesterday, it still got online form my laptop. I even made it become an AP and then other laptops could connect to it. But now.. I cannot even ping to it.